# Wordpress : Re-Edit Content with DoubleClick in the editor

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, dialog, double-click

I created a plugin for WordPress. It opens a dialog box with an `input` field to fill, and then it creates a `div` with the contents of the field. Once the `div` was created in the editor, I would like to be able to doubleclick on this `div` and open the dialog box again.
How should I do it ?

**Here, my PHP FILE :**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: my Plugin
*/
?>

<?php
    function add_myItems(){
?>

    <!-- the Dialog Box -->
    <div id="myDialog">

        <style type="text/css">          
            #myDialog {
                display: none; /* hidden by default */
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 100; /* Sit on top */
                width: 200px; 
                height: 200px;
            }          
        </style>

        <input id="myData" value="" />
        <a href="#" id="myOK">OK</a>

    </div>    

    <!-- the WP button -->
    <a href="#" id="myButton">Add DIV</a>

<?php
    }

    function add_myJS() {
        wp_enqueue_script('myJS', '/wp-content/plugins/my/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_media', 'add_myJS');
    add_action('media_buttons', 'add_myItems');

?>
```

**...and Here, my JS FILE :**

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    $('#myDialog').show();                    
    });

$('#myOK').click( function (){

    var data = $('#myData').val();
    var result ='<div class="myResult">' + data + '</div>';

        wp.media.editor.insert(result); /* the WordPress function */
        $('#myDialog').hide();

    });
```

Thank you for your help. Nicolas.